# Binary Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction, no-computers, sudoku

The rules of Binary Sudoku are quite simple. It is very similar to regular Sudoku, except here we try to fill a 9x9 board with only black and white tiles following the below rules:

1. Every row, column, and $3$x$3$ box (the same nine $3$x$3$ boxes as in regular Sudoku) must have 2 black tiles — no more and no less, which leaves 7 remaining white tiles.
2. Black tiles can never be adjacent to other black tiles (this includes diagonally adjacent, so every tile has 8 adjacent neighbors).

Warm-up question:
How many possible completed boards are there, given we start out with the two black tiles in the middle $3$x$3$ box as shown below?

[image: Grid with two black tiles in central 3x3 box]

Challenging (final) question: Starting with an empty board, how many possible different completed boards are there?

Comment: FYI, this is more well-known as [Star Battle](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/star-battle-rules-and-info/).

Comment: Are computer-aided solutions allowed?

Comment: So it's not [this](https://xkcd.com/74/) Binary Sudoku...

Comment: @bobble My bad, there's no fun in solving the puzzle with a computer, I should have made it more clear by adding a tag, but try to find a non-computer method of solving this puzzle!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no [no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers), and it was easy enough to hack my [Kyoto](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Kyoto) CNF generator to produce a [SAT instance for the problem](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Kyoto/blob/e228c13aa28bda2625b93b1645f2732c7ea41abd/starbattle.py): a 9×9 bit array where each row, column and box has two 1s and no two adjacent variables may be both 1.

> Solving the instance showed that there are exactly nine non-isomorphic (up to rotations/reflections of the whole grid) solutions:
>  [image]
>  Of these only two satisfy the constraint of the first question (marked by a blue centre box). All solutions are totally asymmetric except the central one (which has 4 equivalents), yielding 68 solutions in all, 6 of which satisfy the first question's constraint.

---

[no-computers](/questions/tagged/no-computers) proof:

> [image]
>  This is basically a manual SAT proof, where the first level of cases is the centre cell star configuration (I use [Hensel notation](https://conwaylife.com/wiki/Hensel_notation) for the names). Blue, pink and white stars (mostly) indicate choices while blue backgrounds indicate solutions; note that box centres can never be starred because that would leave no room for the second star.

> Case **n** is very easy to knock out by forced star placement. For **k** R5C9 is not a star because that alongside the (WLOG placed) R5C6 kills all locations for a second star in box 6, so [a star is in] R5C1 and R4C3. Subsequent assumptions, contradictions and inferences are as follows:
>  1. Assume [there is] not [a star in] R9C123, then R8C3 and R7/8C1, then R13C2, × (contradiction). (Slash means "or" and concatenation means "and".)
>  2. Assume R9C1, then R17C2 (col 2 slots), then R3C3, ×.
>  3. Assume R9C3, then R17C2 (col 2 slots), not R8C6, R7C6, R8C79, ×. Hence R9C2.
>  4. Assume R7C1, then R1C2, R3C3, ×. Hence R7C2.
>  5. The two stars in col 5 cannot both be in box 8. Suppose one is, then it is R9C5, then R7C6 and R8C79, ×. Hence R13C5 (box 2).
>  6. Assume R9C4, then not R7C8 (second star of box 9 extinguished, or E9), then R7/8C7. But either choice gives E8. Hence R8C4.
>  7. Assume R7C7, then R8C9, R1C8, R3C7, R4C8, ×. R8C7 gives E8, so R9C7, R7C6, R8C9.
>  8. Assume R8C9, then × as in 7., so R6C8.
>  9. Assume R4C9. This forces a complete solution (#4 in the solution summary above). Hence (for further solutions) R4C8.
>  10. 9. forces R3C1, at which point exactly two of R2C379 may be true and the remaining column is starred in row 1. This yields #7, #8 and #9.

> 1. With case **c** R5C19, then R4C37 are forced. Not R9C5, so R8/9C4 and R8/9C6, so R13C5. Assume R1C2, then R3C1, R7C2, R9C3 and two stars cannot be packed into box 8 (×). Hence the stars in col 2 (and 8 by symmetry) must go in box 7 (9) and R8C46.
>  2–5 are just short further cases that either lead to solutions #1, #2, #3 or a contradiction.

> 1. In case **i** assume (WLOG) R46C1, then R19C2, R37C3, WLOG R1C4, R2C9, R2C7 and R3C5, R7C5/6 and R9C5/6, R8C79, R79C5. But then col 5 has three stars, ×. Hence at least one of R46C2 is true, as is R46C8.
>  2. Assume these stars are *cis*, i.e. R6C28. Exactly one star then lies in each of the four pairs of R8/9C1379, forcing R7C46, R9C37, R8C19.
>  3. Still with the assumption from 2. assume R4C1. This forces the whole of solution #6, so for further search we assume R4C28.
>  4. The latter inference above (built on 2.) leads to row 3 having only one star, ×. The case induced by the choice in 2. has been exhausted.
>  5. We move on to the *trans* case, i.e. R6C2 and R4C8. To avoid repeating the *cis* case we have R4C1 and R6C9. Assume both stars in col 3 are in box 1, then R9C2 and R7C1, ×. Hence exactly one star in col 3 is in box 9.
>  6. Assume R9C3, which forces R1C2 and R8C1. Assume further R7C46, easily forcing a whole grid filled... but col 9 contains three stars, ×.
>  7. Given the first choice in 6. there must be R8C9; together with the whole of 6. this implies R7C7, then R6C9, R1C8, R3C7, R4C8, ×. Hence on col 3 R8C3, and by symmetry R2C7.
>  8. Assume R9C1, then R1C2, R3C3, R2C9, R2C7 and R3C5, R1C5, R79C6. But then col 6 has three stars, ×. Hence R8C1 and by symmetry R2C9.
>  9. From the end of 8. solution #5 is forced all the way.

Comment: Nice! Can you find a no-computer justification to these solutions and why they are the only ones?

Comment: @menalaus done, and you just lost The Game.